# Can I prove the Baire Category Theorem in this bizarre way?

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to prove the Baire Category Theorem, which states that in a complete metric space $X$, the countable union of nowhere dense sets has empty interior.

In a metric space, $A$ being nowhere dense (having empty interior) implies that $\sup\limits_{p\in \overline{A}} d(p,(\overline{A})^c)=0$, where $A^c$ is the complement of $A$ in $X$. However, more weakly, it implies that $\sup\limits_{p\in A} d(p,A^c)=0$. Let us call this second function $f(A)$.

Let us now number the countable set of nowhere dense sets $\{A_1,A_2,\dots,\}$. Let $B_i=A_1\cup\dots \cup A_i$. Now consider the sequence $\{B_1,B_2,\dots\}$. Clearly, $f(B_i)=0$ for all $i\in\Bbb{N}$.

Can we say that $\lim\limits_{i\to\infty} B_i=\cup_{i} A_i$? Also, can we say that $f(A)$ is a continuous function in the *weird* topological space that contains subsets of $X$, and hence we can pass on to the limit and conclude that $f(\cup_i A_i)=0$?

How does the completeness of $X$ play into this? Moreover, how does the fact that $\sup\limits_{p\in \overline{A_i}} d(p,(\overline{A_i})^c)=0$ play into this?

Comment: I hope that where you say "min" you really mean the infimum.

Comment: @NateEldredge- Yes. Now edited

Comment: And keep in mind that "nowhere dense" is not the same as "having empty interior" (only for closed sets).  In general "nowhere dense" is stronger.  The set of rationals in $\mathbb{R}$ has empty interior but isn't nowhere dense.

Comment: What you mean by $\lim_{i\to \infty} B_i=\bigcup_{i} A_i$?

Comment: @NateEldredge- Yes. I am beginning to think that my approach is hopeless. In the process of passing to the limit, I am asking that we prove that the countable union is also nowhere dense, which might be false

Comment: @PtF- Can be embed the $B_i$'s in some topological space such that the $B_i$'s form a sequence whose limit is $\cup_i A_i$?

Comment: I edited, the way you wrote you defined a function $f=0$. Anyway, the problem with your approach is that $f(A)=0$ is not equivalent to $A$ being nowhere dense.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro- Thanks

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro- I have now slightly changed the definition of $f$ such that it should now make sense

Comment: @NateEldredge- I have now edited the definition of $f$ such that things should now make sense

Comment: You're welcome, I actually like the idea, some adaptation might work, but not in the general case, that's too abstract. It may work for $X$ equal to the unit ball in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro- Thanks. I've changed my definition of $f$ to be $\sup$ instead of $\inf$. Don't know if this makes my approach any less hopeless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can we say that $\lim\limits_{i\to\infty} B_i=\cup_{i} A_i$?

Sure, you can think of it that way if you like.

> Also, can we say that $f(A)$ is a continuous function in the *weird* topological space that contains subsets of $X$, and hence we can pass on to the limit and conclude that $f(\cup_i A_i)=0$?

No, that's not true in general.  For instance let $X=[0,1] \cup \{50\}$ with the Euclidean metric. Let $A_1 = \{0\}$ and $A_n = (1/n, 1]$ for $n \ge 2$.  Then $f(A_1 \cup \dots \cup A_n) \le 1$ for every $n$, but $f(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n) = 50$.

It is true that $f(A)=0$ if and only if $A$ has empty interior.  But this is weaker than being nowhere dense, and so this won't help you prove the Baire category theorem.  It is certainly possible that a countable union of sets with empty interior has nonempty interior: enumerate the rationals as $q_1, q_2, \dots$ and let $A_n = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{q_n, q_{n+1}, \dots\}$.

> How does the completeness of $X$ play into this?

It doesn't, really.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just realized that my definition of $\inf$ was wrong. It should have been $\sup$. I have now changed my definition of $f$ accordingly. I don't know if this makes my approach any less hopeless

Comment: I realized that my definition was wrong after seeing that your $A_i$'s are clearly not nowhere dense, but you are still getting $f_(A_i)=0$. This should not have been happening

Comment: @fierydemon: It unfortunately doesn't help.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand why $f(\cup_i A_i)=49$. Shouldn't it just be $\frac{1}{2}$ (I think you meant $\frac{1}{2}$ when you wrote $1$?)?

Comment: Just so that we are interpreting the definition the same way: $f(A)=\sup\limits_{p\in A} d(p,A^c)$, where $d(p,A^c)=\inf\limits_{a\in A^c} d(p,a)$

Comment: @fierydemon: It actually should be 50 (I fixed it).  Because $\bigcup_n A_n = [0,1]$ , its complement consists of the single point $50$, and the maximum distance from a point in $[0,1]$ to $50$ is $50$ (the distance from $0$).

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't realize that the total space was $[0,1]\cup \{50\}$, and not $\Bbb{R}$